# Use Wikipedia as OWL

Tags: wikipedia, owl

How can I export a specific part of Wikipedia? Is there a way to get it in OWL format? I've searched for it but nothing was found. If it's not possible, is there a Wikipedia's service to know if a given string is an specific kind of object, like a book author, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I export a specific part of Wikipedia?

If it's a relatively small number of articles, you can use [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport). If it's lots of articles, the best choice is probably to download [one of the full dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) (most likely `pages-articles`) and work with that.

> Is there a way to get it in OWL format?

As far as I know, Wikipedia doesn't support OWL, so, no.

> Is there a Wikipedia's service to know if a given string is an specific kind of object, like a book author, for example?

You might want to look at [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/) and (in the future) [Wikidata](http://www.wikidata.org/).

Comment: There are plenty of questions on SO about [tag:dbpedia] and getting information out in RDF and OWL.  The dumps can be downloaded directly from DBpedia, and the data can be retrieved through the public SPARQL endpoint.